# Flax implementation of padding_idx from torch.nn.embedding

Tags: python, pytorch, jax, flax

I have been rewriting some of my pytorch models in jax/flax and came across the issue of converting torch.nn.Embedding to flax.linen.Embed.

There does not appear to be a direct translation for pytorch's `padding_idx`. The keyword essentially 0's the embeddings (i.e., no gradients) for cases where the `input==padding_idx`. Working with (dynamic) masking in the jax/flax ecosystem is quite challenging, and thus, I have not been able to figure out a way to functionally translate my simple embedding model from pytorch to flax. Any insight on how to functionally perform a similar padding_idx operation in flax would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you for any help on the issue.

Comment: Can you share your attempts?

Comment: One way to handle this is to update the attention mask with `attention_mask = (tokens != pad_idx)`.